# Gitlab behind HAProxy with ssl termination

Tags: ssl, docker, gitlab, haproxy

I'm trying to setup gitlab behind haproxy. I use the official gitlab docker container and the dockercloud/haproxy container. If i try to connect from my
browser to gitlab i get the following error in gitlab:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2016-09-16_00:24:09.98430 Bad protocol version identification 'GET /users /sign_in HTTP/1.1' from 172.17.0.7 port 49514
```

The haproxy output: (domain, ips and so on changed)

```
00000008:port_80.accept(0008)=0009 from [184.11.129.10:60554]
00000009:port_443.accept(0007)=000a from [184.11.129.10:59956]
00000009:port_443.clireq[000a:ffffffff]: GET / HTTP/1.1
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Host: gitlab.example.com
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11;    Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=c68e65e7d79ef8af9c4aef14e29bed7a
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Connection: keep-alive
00000009:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvrep[000a:000b]: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Server: nginx
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:15:12 GMT
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-Length: 105
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Connection: keep-alive
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Cache-Control: no-cache
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Location: https://gitlab.example.com/users/sign_in
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Set-Cookie: _gitlab_session=2b529bf6639da2b83406dcdf1312c385; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Status: 302 Found
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Request-Id: b97cbe2a-0147-4ccd-9cf1-c80542d35b0f
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Runtime: 0.278044
00000009:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
0000000a:port_443.clireq[000a:000b]: GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Host: gitlab.example.com
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=2b529bf6639da2b83406dcdf1312c385
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Connection: keep-alive
0000000a:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
0000000a:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvcls[000a:000b]
0000000a:SERVICE_GITLAB.clicls[000a:000b]
0000000a:SERVICE_GITLAB.closed[000a:000b]
00000008:port_80.clicls[0009:ffffffff]
00000008:port_80.closed[0009:ffffffff]
0000000b:port_443.accept(0007)=000b from [184.11.129.10:59990]
0000000c:port_443.accept(0007)=000a from [184.11.129.10:59994]
0000000d:port_443.accept(0007)=0009 from [184.11.129.10:59992]
0000000b:port_443.clireq[000b:ffffffff]: GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Host: gitlab.example.com
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Connection: keep-alive
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Cache-Control: max-age=0
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=efd1f2dca673f443a756b93743097228
0000000b:port_443.clihdr[000b:ffffffff]: If-None-Match: W/"bc26f64dfe227748fcff77508b9b63c5"
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvrep[000b:000c]: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Server: nginx
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:15:20 GMT
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Content-Length: 153
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Connection: keep-alive
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Cache-Control: no-cache
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Location: https://gitlab.example.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=BpNnrPG4mrQ3h85hqrgz
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Set-Cookie: _gitlab_session=0f9ecb6d6096e6809e151f5d8654394b; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: Status: 302 Found
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: X-Request-Id: c67da4bd-5d84-46e5-bc1c-6b382991c27c
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: X-Runtime: 0.672426
0000000b:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000b:000c]: X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
0000000e:port_443.clireq[000b:000c]: GET /users/password/edit?reset_password_token=BpNnrPG4mrQ3h85hqrgz HTTP/1.1
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Host: gitlab.example.com
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Connection: keep-alive
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Cache-Control: max-age=0
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
0000000e:port_443.clihdr[000b:000c]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=0f9ecb6d6096e6809e151f5d8654394b
0000000e:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvcls[000b:000c]
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=2b529bf6639da2b83406dcdf1312c385
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Connection: keep-alive
00000017:port_443.clihdr[000a:ffffffff]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvrep[000a:000b]: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Server: nginx
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:24:09 GMT
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Content-Length: 105
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Connection: keep-alive
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Cache-Control: no-cache
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Location: https://gitlab.example.com/users/sign_in
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: Status: 302 Found
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Request-Id: 43311710-97be-439b-87ea-a5bee9e7a6d3
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Runtime: 0.296297
00000017:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvhdr[000a:000b]: X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
00000018:port_443.clireq[000a:000b]: GET /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Host: gitlab.example.com
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Cookie: _gitlab_session=2b529bf6639da2b83406dcdf1312c385
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Connection: keep-alive
00000018:port_443.clihdr[000a:000b]: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
00000018:SERVICE_GITLAB.srvcls[000a:000b]
00000018:SERVICE_GITLAB.clicls[000a:000b]
00000018:SERVICE_GITLAB.closed[000a:000b]
00000016:port_80.clicls[0009:ffffffff]
00000016:port_80.closed[0009:ffffffff]
```

This is how i start the gitlab container (domain and stuff changed):

```
docker run --detach \
--expose 80 --expose 22 \
--hostname gitlab.example.com
--name gitlab \
--restart always \
--env VIRTUAL_HOST=https://gitlab.example.com,gitlab.example.com \
--env FORCE_SSL=yes \
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

This is the docker compose file for haproxy:

```
version: '2'
services:
  haProxy:
    image: dockercloud/haproxy
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - /srv/certs:/certs/
    external_links:
        - gitlab:gitlab
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
        - 9090:9090
    environment:
        - STATS_AUTH="dummy:dummy"
        - STATS_PORT=9090
        - CERT_FOLDER=/certs/
        - FORCE_SSL=yes
        - EXTRA_GLOBAL_SETTINGS="debug"
    network_mode: "bridge"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bridge
```

Any tips are very appreciated!

Thany you!

Answer (score 1):

You're not really terminating SSL with HAProxy here - your GitLab container is publishing port 80 so it's listening publicly for HTTP traffic, but you're also using `FORCE_SSL` so I don't think it will answer on HTTP.

To do SSL at the proxy layer, you can remove the `FORCE_SSL` from GitLab so it runs on HTTP, and make the connection from HAProxy to GitLab private, so the only way to access GitLab is via HAProxy.

If you put GitLab as a service in the same Docker Compose file as HAProxy, then you don't need to publish port 80 from GitLab. When you `docker-compose up -d` the containers will run in the same Docker network and the proxy container will be able to access GitLab by its container name on any ports exposed in the image (you don't have to publish ports for containers in the same network to communicate).

Alternatively, if GitLab is all you're running then you don't need HAProxy - you can [Enable HTTPS in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#enable-https) itself.

Comment: The FORCE_SSL environment variable is used by HAProxy. I don't think it has effect for gitlab itself.

I have multiple services running and I don't want them in a single docker compose file. This is the reason why I start the services independently.